# CF_IPCountry header to all requests in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, ip, cloudflare

I'm starting a blog in Drupal and using Cloudflare DNS. They act as a 'proxy' and all my visitors have their ip. They offer an IP Geolocation option to show real users IP:

> Once enabled, we will then add a header called "CF-IPCountry" to all requests we make to your website. Here are a couple of examples of how to access/store this value:
>
> $country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]; // to access in PHP
>
> $country_code = $ENV{"HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"}; # to access in Perl

The question is: how can I use this?

I'm a html/css/js person and making now my first steps into php. I searched this last two days and didn't found a single example how to implement this option. I tried this in the "template.php" file:

```
function TEMPLATE_drupal_add_http_header() {
  $country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
}
```

But nothing happens and ip's still from Cloudflare. Can anyone help here? Is it so simple that it doesn't need any explanations (hence I didn't found one)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like the [Drupal plugin installed](https://www.drupal.org/project/cloudflare) or something like [mod_cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads)?